# Openfire - how to access discussion history on server?

Tags: openfire

Is there a way to access Discussion History on Openfire server and delete a specific message before it is delivered to a group chat user ? I looked up all the tables but could not find out where discussion history is stored.

Appreciate your help in getting this resolved.

Comment: Do you want to eliminate a message "forever" or just avoid to send message X to user Y ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this query from you. I need to remove a message from server so that it is eliminated forever.

Comment: By discussion history, you mean one-one chat history OR group chat history?

Comment: One item from Group chat history